# Liferay Hook customization

Tags: hook, liferay

I wanted to write a hook which will place a new field in new document type along with present ones(textbox, selectbox etc.)."I need That new field which works like dropdown box under Metadatasets as screen shot shows .and also i need to get values from database whenever i select that field in the available fields if we choose "select" it show option1 ,option2 ,option3 .."

Can anyone know which js and jsp files should I edit.? Please help

https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen04-document-types-and-metadata-sets-0

i was unable to upload image,Can u plz see the above link.in this page figure 4.6 is the image.

Comment: 1) And what would be that new field? and why would it be used? I ask these question so that an alternative can be provided if it exist because customizing liferay's jsp with javascript even with a hook should be taken up with utmost caution since you never know what else it can break.
2) Also it is not clear which page you are talking about, are you talking about [this page](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen04-document-types-and-metadata-sets-0). Please  include details in your question, some screen-shots will help.

Comment: If you can specify where you want to add, it would help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Document Types` are part of Document library so you can check-out: `\portal-web\docroot\html\portlet\document_library\edit_file_entry_type.jsp`. and other related pages which might be accessed from this page.

Hope this is what you want, again I would suggest to please pay heed to my [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176172/liferay-hook-customization#comment17934746_13176172) to your question.

Comment: Thanks prakash for this information.I need to populate data from the database for this dropdown box when i select this field,any suggestions please..